# Cannot destructure an object fetched from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, react-context

I fetched and object which contains two properties, one is a number and one is an array. So I right away accessed the array and then assigned to a state and then passed each item to another component through context api. And it does not working. Here is my code:

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);
const [i, setI] = useState(0);

const fetchUrl = async() => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    setInfo(data.results);
    setLoading(false);
} 

useEffect(() => {
    fetchUrl();
}, []);

const {correct_answer, incorrect_answers, question} = info[i];
const arr = [correct_answer, ...incorrect_answers].sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);
```

In this code 'correct_answer' is a string and 'incorrect_answers' is an array.
After running this code it says:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'correct_answer' of 'info[i]' as it is undefined.
```

And sometimes it says:

```
TypeError: 'incorrect_answers' is not iterable.
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look you defined `i` anywhere. The error you are getting is because `info[i]` is returning undefined.

The second error could be due to `incorrect_answers` either being undefined or just not an array.

The problem is likely that `fetchUrl` is executing asynchronously, and you are setting these other variables that probably depend on `fetchUrl` to complete, without waiting on `fetchUrl` to complete.